# Cocos2d scaling sprite causes artifact

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I am on the master branch so that it will work with ARC.

I have implemented a method whereby the sprite will scale by a factor of 1.1 when a user touches the sprite. Multiple touches will queue up multiple scaling actions, built on top of each other. Every now and then I get a strange artifact where the smaller version of the sprite shows up on top of the scaled version.

Here's a screenshot: [image]

More background: I'm using a texture atlas so I use:

```
    sprite = [super spriteWithSpriteFrameName:anObject.filename];
```

to initialize the sprite. Is this a bug in openGL/cocos2d? Any advice on how to stop this artifact?

EDIT: 
I am subclassing CCSprite but as far as I can tell there is only one instance of the sprite (the call to super was in a class method). Basically the user will define a list of actions that the sprite will do. The action list can also be interrupted using:

```
[self stopAllActions]
```

I've had actions using subclasses of CCMoveBy and CCRotateBy with no issues. It's only the most recent subclass of CCScaleBy that is causing this artifact. In the subclasses of these actions I'm not changing anything in the actions, just tracking certain variables so that I can properly resume the action after the interrupt.

Comment: Why are you using super? Shouldn't it just be [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:name];? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps subclassing CCSprite, and in your subclass did you add a CCSprite instance variable as well?

In that case you'll be showing two sprites. The super class sprite and the instance variable sprite. If the other sprite shows up only sometimes this may depend on the order of adding sprites as childs, or the zOrder property.

Comment: I am subclassing CCSprite but I don't think there is CCSprite instance variable. I do, though, create several more CCSprites from within my CCSprite class in order to draw a line behind the sprite as it moves but that has been going on for a while without issue. The artifact has only appeared when I used CCScaleby which does not draw a motion streak.